# Http failure during parsing for MY_REST_URL

Tags: json, angular, http, parsing

in my angular application, my rest api call is blocked  with this error:

**Http failure during parsing for MY_REST_URL**

This is occuring when my payload contains "UNION" or "SELECT" keywords as the value of a field. Example:
payload= {"name" : "bob", "lastName":"UNION"}

If UNION/SELECT is replaced by any other value, then I get the response with no problem

Comment: May be it is issue with rest api.

Comment: What about validation of rest api on each property?